# The tag [literate-programming] is filled with questions about loops (iteration)

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

When entering "iterate" into the tag search box for a new question, [literate-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/literate-programming) is indeed one of the suggested tags...

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this from happening? It's an obscure topic and I'm always excited at first if there is a new question, but then disappointed to see that it is unrelated.

Comment: Clearly the tag needs to state **DO NOT USE this tag for questions about iteration.** In it's excerpt so that users can continue to ignore not just the descriptive text but the big capital letters that are force fed to them. ;)

Comment: @Larnu:  Could we just have the first three words and kinda omit the rest? I'm really struggling to see how this tag isn't a meta tag of some description.  If you're doing literal programming with a library, surely you'd be asking about that library instead as opposed to the general concept, right?

Comment: My comment is meant in jest more than anything, @Makoto , on the basis that even for on topic tags users don't bother to read [the excerpt]. That new users don't even take the Tour and so have no idea what the site is about... /Facepalm

Comment: @Larnu: Yep, just more text for someone to ignore.  Always a good time had by all. :D

Comment: A terrible pun is missing in the title. *'How many iterations do il[literate programm]ers' need?'*

Comment: 'How many iterations do il[literate-programming] people' need?' to get the tag right. @PeterMortensen

Comment: People who misread the literate-programming tag are illiterate programmers.

Answer (score 22):

Honestly, there's a lot of problems with this tag.  Some folks read too fast and read "literate" as "iterate" and are putting their iteration questions here.

Other questions which *do* talk about literate programming are probably too broad to cover in the scope of the site anyway ([exhibit A, already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267280/1079354)).

Maybe this is a call for those who *are* familiar with literate programming to go through this tag and start cleaning things up.  **Don't *just* remove the tag from the question.  Take the time and make the effort to really clean things up.**

Maybe this is also a call to look at the tag's actual viability on the site.  The more I read of this, the less tangible I feel that the subject matter actually is.  Who would ask a question about this except in the context of, "well, how do I do it?", which unto itself feels like a question about "well, how do I build a forum?"

Comment: I agree, that all the legit questions refer to a specific literate programming tool anyways, so the need for this tag is questionable. The concept itself is something for people who want to teach programming, so they should be knowing what they're doing instead of asking questions here :P

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack It's worth noting that there are separate sites for both [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) which might be a better fit for the theoretical aspects. In some cases, [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be suitable as well.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like this tag needs to be burninated. [The four burnination criteria test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640)

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

The excerpt says

> A literate program embeds source code in an essay documenting the program.

It's not clear that this is a topic for SO (writing an essay isn't our thing). It's also clear that most of the questions are not about essays at all, which means it's ambiguous why the tag is there.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Based on the excerpt, no. It's not clear what on-topic usage it could have, either.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

I suspect a number of people are adding this for the reasons the questioner mentioned: it shows up for "iterate" ([case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555252/python-iterate-loop-over-two-columns-and-drop-entire-row-after-value-is-first)).

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Again, it's not clear what on-topic usage it could have, so there is no common context.

Comment: Literate programming in general is legitimately on topic for SO, it seems to me.  It's a particular style of programming, but is supported by tools (compilers, or more accurately, pre-compilers) etc.  So, questions about how to program with literate programming tools or how to solve problems when using them could be OK.  When it's accurate, the tag adds useful information (you can code using literate programming in C, using `ctangle` and `cweb`), but if it is not tagged with the [tag:literate-programming] tag too, it would confuse people a lot.  When it's misused, it is unhelpful.

Comment: I just had to remove the [tag:sam] tag from a [question about ARM/AVR vs SAM microcontrollers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954341/diffrences-between-arm-and-sam-programming) because the tag is for a PHP feature ("Simple Asynchronous Messaging is a PHP framework") and not related to microcontrollers at all.  The tag was simply misused.  That can happen to any tag.  (I've had to retag questions tagged [tag:c] with [tag:c#] when the code was clearly not C and was for C#.)

Comment: This answer misses the point. Literate programming has nothing to do with essays. It's a style of programming where you mix code and documentation, so that from the same file you can extract pure sources, and a document (I guess that's the essay) that is beautifully formatted and annotated source. Literate programming was invented by Knuth for writing TeX. It is totally on topic for SO.

Comment: Literate programming is a stylistic choice, akin to tabs vs spaces. it in and of itself is not a topic useful to SO's goal. tools that *support* that stylistic choice might be on topic, such as extensions to editors or build processes that convert it into real documentation, however they should have their own tags.

Comment: I'd like to invite the commenters to post answers in support of this tag. That way, we get a post that can be voted on.

Comment: @KevinB "stylistic choice" Hm. I'd call it a philosophy. It's definitely way more than just a style.

Comment: From the sound of it, literate programming is somewhat on a par with Git flow, likely to evoke opinion based discussion and hence not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Literate programming is a methodology (philosophy?) of program development, on par with "top down" and "bottom up" programming. As such it's worthy of discussion, but it's also somewhat hard to imagine questions strictly about literate programming. On the other hand, just as one could post a question tagged "sorting" and "C++", one could ask about literate programming and some particular support tool, or its application in some particular problem domain.

And, historical note, literate programming was invented by Donald Knuth to develop TeX. If that alone doesn't qualify it as a SO topic...

Comment: Is this a better topic for [softwareengineering.se] maybe?

Comment: @Machavity Sounds like a reasonable suggestion. But I'm no expert on the boundaries between SO/SE communities.

Comment: I mean, yeah, but this is rarely relevant in a practical sense. This is too high up in the stack for more down to earth implementations, like the kind of questions that are usual on SO.